# Quotient group of smaller rank?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-simple finite group with minimal number of generators $d(G)=n\geq 2$.

Does $G$ necessarily have a non-trivial quotient $H$ with $d(H)<n$?

Comment: For $n=1$, how could we have $d(H)<1$?

Comment: Even ignoring the cyclic case, one can take say $G=SL(2,5)$, which is 2-generated, but has no cyclic quotient.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The trivial group $H$ has $d(H)=0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt The OP wanted $H$ to be non-trivial.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde You're right of course, I meant $n\geq 2$. I edited the question.

Comment: @verret Thanks for the (embarrasingly simple) example. Now that I lknow they exist, allow me to take the question to the next level: Is there anything that characterizes such groups, i.e. groups whose every quotient has the same rank as the group itself?

Comment: At first blush this seems to me like a wild family. Another example would be $A_5^{15}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if one can say much more that they must be perfect groups. Perhaps Derek can say more, because he knows a lot about perfect groups.

Comment: @verret Thanks. It gave me a direction. If you think about anything additional, I'll be glad to hear.